# Cross-compiling Coqui + TFLite for armv7ahf in Yocto: R_ARM_TLS_LE32 relocation not permitted in shared object

Tags: tensorflow, eigen, yocto, bazel, coqui

I'm trying to do a Yocto build of `libstt.so` from the Coqui project, with TFLite as the backend, for the Snapdragon 210 which has an armv7ahf processor. I've been using the `meta-tensorflow` OpenEmbedded layer as a starting point.

Getting Bazel compiled and working with the Yocto cross-compilation toolchain was heinously complicated, but that's happily behind me now, and my layer has progressed to building `libstt.so` itself.

However, towards the end of the build in the linking phase I get this `R_ARM_TLS_LE32 relocation not permitted in shared object` error:

```
ld: bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/kernels/libeigen_support.pic.a(eigen_support.pic.o)(.text._ZNK6tflite13eigen_support12_GLOBAL__N_122EigenThreadPoolWrapper15CurrentThreadIdEv+0x2c): R_ARM_TLS_LE32 relocation not permitted in shared object
bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/kernels/libeigen_support.pic.a(eigen_support.pic.o): In function `tflite::eigen_support::(anonymous namespace)::EigenThreadPoolWrapper::CurrentThreadId() const':
eigen_support.cc:(.text._ZNK6tflite13eigen_support12_GLOBAL__N_122EigenThreadPoolWrapper15CurrentThreadIdEv+0x2c): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
```

I gather that `R_ARM_TLS_LE32` is an ELF static Thread Local Storage relocation code, and that `eigen_support` is incorrectly being compiled with static code that the linker won't accept? But I'm definitely out of my depth here.

The build is being initiated with:

```
bazel build \
        --config=monolithic \
        --verbose_explanations --verbose_failures \ 
        --action_env ANDROID_NDK_API_LEVEL=21 \     
        --config=android  \
        --config=android_arm \
        --define runtime=tflite \
        --cxxopt="-fpermissive" \
        --cxxopt="-std=c++14"  \
        --cpu="${BAZEL_TARGET_CPU}" \
        -c opt \
        --copt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" \
        --copt=-fvisibility=hidden \
        --copt=-O3 \
        --copt=-D_GLIBCXX_USE_C99 \
        --crosstool_top=@local_config_yocto_compiler//:toolchain \
        --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
        --subcommands --explain=${T}/explain.log \
        //native_client:libstt.so
}
```

`eigen_support.pic.o` itself is built with the following command (from the error log, formatted for ease of reading). Can you help me figure out why it's compiling wrong?

```
arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
-fstack-protector 
-g0 
-O2 
-DNDEBUG 
-ffunction-sections 
-fdata-sections 
-D_PYTHON_INCLUDE_TARGET 
-MD 
-MF bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/kernels/_objs/eigen_support/eigen_support.pic.d 
'-frandom-seed=bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/kernels/_objs/eigen_support/eigen_support.pic.o' 
-fPIC 
-DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY 
'-DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=64' 
'-DEIGEN_HAS_TYPE_TRAITS=0' 
-iquote . 
-iquote bazel-out/arm-opt/bin 
-iquote external/gemmlowp 
-iquote bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/external/gemmlowp 
-iquote external/eigen_archive 
-iquote bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive 
-iquote external/local_config_sycl 
-iquote bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/external/local_config_sycl 
-iquote external/ruy 
-iquote bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/external/ruy 
-iquote external/cpuinfo 
-iquote bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/external/cpuinfo 
-iquote external/clog 
-iquote bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/external/clog 
-Ibazel-out/arm-opt/bin/external/clog/_virtual_includes/clog 
-isystem external/eigen_archive 
-isystem bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive 
-DTFLITE_WITH_RUY_GEMV 
-w 
-w 
-fPIC 
-D_GLIBCXX_USE_C99 
-D_PYTHON_INCLUDE_TARGET 
'-march=armv7-a' 
'-mfpu=neon' 
'-mfloat-abi=hard' 
-Wl,-O1 
'-Wl,--hash-style=gnu' 
-Wl,--as-needed 
-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now,-z,noexecstack 
-fstack-protector-strong 
-pie -fPIE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 
-Wa,--noexecstack 
-Wformat -Wformat-security '-Werror=format-security' 
'--sysroot=/home/gbw/sc20_linux/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7ahf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/coqui/v0.10.0-alpha.9-r0/bazel/output_base/external/yocto_compiler/recipe-sysroot' 
-O2 
-Wa,--noexecstack 
-fexpensive-optimizations 
-frename-registers 
-fomit-frame-pointer 
-ftree-vectorize 
-finline-functions 
'-finline-limit=64' 
'-Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized' 
'-Wno-error=unused-result' 
-fvisibility-inlines-hidden 
'-std=c++14' 
'-std=c++14' -fpermissive 
'-std=c++14' 
-DFARMHASH_NO_CXX_STRING 
-Wno-sign-compare 
-O3 
-fno-exceptions 
'-Wno-error=reorder' 
-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined 
'-D__DATE__="redacted"' 
'-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' 
'-D__TIME__="redacted"' 
-no-canonical-prefixes 
-fno-canonical-system-headers 
-c tensorflow/lite/kernels/eigen_support.cc 
-o bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/kernels/_objs/eigen_support/eigen_support.pic.o)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the `-fPIE` compiler flag being added by a bazelrc file that I didn't notice. Removing `-fPIE` fixed the error.